# AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm getting following error on heroku after uploading file through paperclip.

> AWS::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect (The bucket you are attempting to
>   access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all
>   future requests to this endpoint.)

This is my settings in the model

```
has_attached_file :profile_image,
 :styles => { :myrecipes => "260x180#"},
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_region => 'us-west-1',
 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
 :path => "/images/:id/:style.:extension",
 :url => ":s3_domain_url"
```

This is working on development and store image on S3 but while I'm trying on production (Heroku) I'm getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Provide the endpoint you have to do add this into your paperclip_defaults

```
:s3_host_name => "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Or you can do like this

```
s3_host_name: "s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com"
```

Ref: [paperclip issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151)

Comment: Change `:url => ":s3_domain_url"` to `:url => ":s3_host_name"`